# Para que serve o "with" no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, with

Para que serve o `with` no JavaScript?

Ele funciona apenas para obter os valores do objeto como se fosse uma variável, ou também é possível definir ou alterar propriedades através dele?

Exemplo:

```
var obj = {nome: 'Stack Overflow'}

with (obj) {
  console.log(nome); //Imprime: 'Stack Overflow'
}
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

É apenas para facilitar a digitação quando você vai acessar vários membros de um objeto.

Como o seu exemplo mostra você pode digitar apenas `nome` e não precisou digitar `obj.nome` para acessar o membro.

O ganho é muito pequeno e ele pode trazer problemas de ambiguidade por isto não é recomendado o seu uso. Considere como algo não existente na linguagem. Claro que você pode usar em algum caso onde fique claro não há ambiguidade e que você vai acessar muitos membros de um objeto de um nome muito longo, mas ainda assim o ganho é muito pequeno.

A ambiguidade pode ocorrer porque você já não sabe se está acessando uma variável local (incluindo parâmetro), global, uma propriedade existente no protótipo ou se está se referindo a um membro do objeto. Exemplo usando seu objeto:

```
function f(nome, obj) {
    with (obj) {
        console.log(nome);
    }
}
```

E agora, qual `nome` ele vai usar, o parâmetro ou o membro de `obj`? Note que a coisa fica pior se você tiver uma variável global chama `nome` - apesar que não deveria ter variáveis globais.

Se você tem um nome de objeto muito grande e acha que além de digitar muito (se não tem um IDE que ajude) ou o texto fica muito grande pode resolver isto tornando o nome bem curto. E se chama que economizar a digitação do `o.` é importante, aí deveria repensar seus critérios de codificação:

```
var o = objeto_de_nome_muito_grande_mas_que_nao_deveria_ter_sido_nomeado_assim;
console.log(o.nome);
```

Usando o `with`:

```
with({o:objeto_de_nome_muito_grande_mas_que_nao_deveria_ter_sido_nomeado_assim}){
    console.log(o.nome);
};
```

Os exemplos servem apenas para demonstração. Evidentemente só vale fazer isto se vai usar o objeto várias vezes.

Como sempre, se você tiver uma boa razão em uma situação específica e tiver plena consciência que não haverá problemas ali, pode até usar. De fato, há quem demonstre a [boa utilidade do `with`](http://webreflection.blogspot.com.br/2009/12/with-some-good-example.html). Esta pode ser uma forma legítima de uso:

```
with({f:open("x.txt")}){
    var data = f.read(1);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/With.js).

Em [*strict mode*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) não é possível usar esta sintaxe.

[Documentação na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: Muito bom! O ActionScript possui também, agora vejo o motivo de muitos programadores não usá-lo!

Comment: @bigown, vejo uma utilidade no caso de um template engine. Pois, ao invés de acessarmos o escopo através do objeto passado por parâmetro, podemos usar `with` para acessar como se as propriedades fossem a variável. Exemplo clássico é o `underscore.js`. tem um trecho parecido com esse: `with(obj || {}) {}`

Comment: A resposta do amigo Marco Paulo Ollivier (abaixo) também é muito pertinente pois aborda scopos, que é algo que as vezes confunde em javascript pelo fato de que blocos simples não criam scopo.

Comment: O uso que o bigdown chamou de legítimo é uma declaração de variável a nível de bloco. Talvez ele pudesse deixar isso mais claro na resposta.

Comment: Apenas como curiosidade, "with" é muito antigo, apareceu na liguagem Pascal original do Wirth.

Comment: Interessante, nem sabia que isso existia na linguagem JavaScript, nunca precisei usar algo do tipo em minhas aplicações, acredito que não conhecia o "with" mais por este motivo, e pelo que entendi, é facilmente substituível pela construção normalizada.

Comment: Sobre o tal, [vale uma lida neste artigo](https://marcuscf.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/o-with-em-linguagens-de-programacao/)

Answer (score 13):

Em JavaScript, `with` é um recurso da linguagem capaz de driblar o escopo léxico, ou seja, independente da ordem de arranjo das variáveis, `with` tomará uma expressão passada como referência como seu escopo.
É a maneira nativa de estender o escopo de uma instrução, funcionando como um atalho para os acessos recorrentes à uma expressão.

```
function foo(x, respostas) {
with (respostas) {
       x = 2; // Estamos atribuindo um novo valor à variável x dentro de o
}

if( (x + x) === respostas.x) { // 1 + 1 = 2 ?
       console.log('Sabemos somar');
}

console.log('Confira a resposta: ' + (x + x)); // Ooops ... retorna 4; isso pode não ser esperado
}

var o = {
       y : 2
};

f(1,o);
```

Caso o objeto passado por referência para o `with` não possua um dos atributos manipulados, o compilador elevará sua declaração para o escopo mais próximo na hierarquia, no nosso caso o escopo de `foo`. Nenhum aviso será lançado e a variável será alterada no escopo mais próximo. Caso este possua um identificador com a mesma denominação, o Compilador realizará uma atribuição (LHS: lefthand-side) e nosso valor no contexto de `foo` se perderá.

**Fonte: https://javaniaco.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/blocos-como-escopo-a-declaracao-with/**

Answer (score 3):

No JavaScript é polêmico. Há alguns anos, a mozila mostrava como `deprecated` na documentação, por volta de 2010. Mais tarde foi removido dessa condição colocado apenas um aviso para evitar o uso. Ainda é incerto se realmente será removido ou não.

Atualmente o aviso na documentação é bastante explítico sobre a importância em NÃO usar. Portanto é importante seguir a recomendação.

Particularmente nunca usei da forma como nos exemplos das outras respostas. Sempre usei apenas para auxiliar no acesso a propriedades de um objeto. Como exemplo, "simular" o `namespace` como no PHP.

<sub>É óbvio que passa longe da funcionalidade de namespace no PHP.</sub>

Exemplo:

```
<script>

Foo = {
    Sample1: function (param1, param2) {
        return param1 + ' statement is ' + param2 + '.';
    },
    Sample2: function () {
        return 'don\'t cry, baby';
    }
};

with(Foo) {
    document.write(Sample1('with', 'deprecated') + ' ' + Sample2());
}
</script>
```

O código fica limpo mais limpo.

Se possuía funções com nomes iguais, sob contextos diferentes, bastava criar um "namespace" para ambas e ficava resolvido de forma "elegante".

É um recurso bacana que ajuda a organizar o código evitando conflitos entre scripts de bibliotecas distintas. <sub>*Quando estão organizados dentro do escopo de um objeto.</sub>.

Ainda funciona e vai funcionar por mais alguns anos. Talvez até 2025 ou pouco mais tarde (inventei o ano aqui na hora, blz?). Mas devemos seguir a recomendação da documentação. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Apenas postei isso porque não vi em nenhuma das outras respostas, altamente positivadas, falar sobre a recomendação em NÃO USAR o `statement with`.

<sub>Obs: O exemplo acima é didático com finalidade de ilustrativa. Pois o foco aqui não é sobre como simular namespace.</sub>

Comment: Acho que seria injusto a pergunta continuar com -1 já que você fez a edição. +1