# O que é Fluent Interface?

Tags: design-pattern, terminologia, estilo-de-codificação

Li rapidamente alguns artigos sobre **Fluent Interface** porém não consegui entender claramente este padrão.

Definição Wikipedia:

> É uma implementação de uma API orientada a
> objeto que tem o objetivo de fornecer o código mais legível.

O que é Fluent Interface e em qual contexto é recomendável sua utilização?

Comment: Segue um artigo que vai lhe explicar isso perfeitamente: http://gc.blog.br/2008/03/03/um-exemplo-pratico-de-fluent-interface/

Comment: Relacionada: [Encadeamento de métodos?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/91)

Comment: Ou estou ficando louco ou não sei. EU já vi essa questão mil vezes aqui no SO.

Comment: Só se for SO-en, faça um teste e pesquise aqui por: `Fluent Interface`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

É uma forma de nomear métodos para serem usados em uma construção que dê a impressão de estar escrevendo um texto corrente, fluido. Ele desiste de uma nomenclatura comum e padronizada para adotar algo que faça sentido quando o método for usado tentando simular um texto fluente em língua humana. É uma forma de deixar o código mais declarativo.

Para conseguir isto estes métodos retornam sempre o objeto que ele está manipulando, assim o próximo método pode ser usado em sequência. Isto é chamado de [encadeamento de método](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Exemplo:

```
MailMessage.builder()
    .from("eu@dominio.com")
    .to("voce@dominio.com.br")
    .subject("oi")
    .message("Oi pra vc")
    .send();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Fluent.cs).

Ele pode eliminar certa repetição de código. Mas repetição não pode ser confundida com violação de [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101). O código fica maior, mas ele não atrapalha a canonicidade, que é o mais importante no DRY.

## Onde é usado

- O LINQ do .NET é um caso típico de uso de interface fluente. A linguagem até permite usar uma forma mais fluente podendo evitar o uso de pontuação, parênteses, etc. Ainda que as pessoas não costumam usar de forma tão fluente assim. Em geral seria interessante criar abstrações para usar com LINQ, mas as pessoas fazem o uso do acesso mais concreto às coleções tornando um pouco menos fluente.
- É muito usado em [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) já que ele prega que o código deve refletir o mais próximo possível do que o domínio determinada. Ele incentiva praticamente o uso de uma [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). para expressar o que deseja e a interface fluente aproxima código comum do que um DSL faz, sem ter que produzir a DSL específica, com o perdão da redundância.
- BDD é outro uso. Principalmente quando se usa metodologias como o [RSpec](http://rspec.info/).
- Em produção de testes também é comum. Especialmente TDD. Testes não devem ser códigos complexos e precisam ser bem claros o que estão fazendo. A fluência do texto pode ajudar.
- Ela parece ser bem útil quando se usa o [`Builder pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) e outros padrões semelhantes e derivados (algumas pessoas confundem este padrão com a interface fluida.

## Crítica

É questionável se dá legibilidade ao código. Dá fluência, isto é indiscutível. Legibilidade é outra coisa.

Pessoalmente nunca vi o ganho que os proponentes dizem. O pouco que tentei usar não me pareceu ser uma ferramenta que traz benefícios reais, pelo menos nos casos que tentei. Acho que até certo ponto é interessante o uso, mas ficar tentando fazer verdadeiras redações é exagerado. É claro que é apenas uma opinião, mas assim como não posso fundamentar isto, nunca vi fundamentação de que há vantagem. Entendo o gosto pelo estilo e vejo qual é a vantagem, só não vejo valor suficiente nela.

Vi pessoas fazerem atrocidades com classes e métodos só para atender este "requisito". Como qualquer ferramenta se mau usada é melhor não usar. Nem sempre é fácil implementá-la.

O programador começa ter que ficar pensando muito no mecanismo e não na regra de negócio, que é o contrário do que a técnica prega. Entendo que a técnica é usada para facilitar o consumidor e não o produtor e que há casos que não há um *overhead* grande na codificação. Mas o problema nunca está no uso básico, e este é o problemas da adoção das ferramentas, a pessoa adota olhando pro básico, quando ela começa se deparar com problemas mais complexos ela sofre mais. E como se apegou à ferramenta não quer admitir que não era tão boa assim.

Não estou dizendo que não serve pra nada e que seja um modismo totalmente sem sentido. Mas que muitas pessoas usam só pela moda, isto está claro pra mim. Como tudo, tem que saber quando é vantajoso de verdade.

Um exemplo do que estou dizendo é a forma como o LINQ é usado. Acho que abstrair os "filtros" que serão usados neles, até para torná-los mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) é muito mais importante que tornar a consulta fluente. Eu vejo mais preocupação com a fluência do que a abstração, isso é generalizado.

Perguntas assim me faz pensar como tudo que é nomeado ?DD parece trazer vantagens, claro, mas também como se tenta consertar o que não estava quebrado. Me parece cada vez mais claro que tudo que é adotado em nichos, isto ocorre por alguma razão. O problema é quando o programador começa achar que ele está naquele nicho, quando não está.

## Alternativas de implementação

Algumas linguagens possuem outras formas de fazer isto com [parâmetros opcionais e nomeados](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou pré-processamento ou [inicializadores de objetos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), até mesmo [propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) ajudariam. Pode ser mais interessante que a técnica de encadeamento de método. Pelo menos evitam atrocidades. Se tivesse uma forma de [`with`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52604/101) bem feito evitaria muitos casos assim.

Exemplos úteis podem ser encontrados em [Como e quando construir um objeto em estado válido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101).

## Referência

Uma das melhores referências é a [página do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) que foi um dos criadores do termo.

Comment: Resposta honesta mas que vai despertar a ira dos fanboys :)

Comment: Coincidentemente eu leio isso hoje, não está diretamente relacionado, mas tangencia o que estou falando sobre usar o que não agrega valor de fato, que cria um fardo. https://medium.com/@puppybits/stop-unit-testing-everything-e1afb20a5ab3#.10cx81lqw E é claro que algumas pessoas vão achar que estou dizendo que não precisa testar nada. Porque quem decide usar uma ferramenta sem um critério não pode ver o meio termo, a ponderação, ou você é camarada ou inimigo daquilo.

Comment: <rant>É problema de geração cultural. Se você não segue cegamente a moda, é considerado dinossauro. Só que pouca gente tem noção de que tudo isso foi construido e só é mantido pelos poucos dinossauros que não foram extintos, senão já tinha ido pro ralo faz tempo.</rant>