# Método dentro de método ou classe dentro de classe

Tags: c#, .net, método

Criados os métodos `Above(), Below(), Highest(), Lowest(), Evens(), Odds(), Matching(), Repeating(), Unique()`...

Preciso criar uma estrutura/implementar estes métodos um dentro do outro, como se estivessem organizados em diretórios, dentro de uma classe `Roll()`.

O objetivo é que aqueles que tentarem utilizar a classe `Roll`, consigam deixar o código deles o mais próximo do linguajar humano:

```
ApplyDamage (Physical (Roll (5,d6).Sum.OnlyEvens.Above(2)), ChosenTarget);
```

Exemplo:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Roll
{
    List<int>   scores;
    int         maxRange;
    public void Roll(int amountOfDices, int maxRange)
    {
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDices; i++)
        {
             scores.Add(Random.Range(1,maxRange));
        }
    }//Construtor

    public int Sum (scores)//este é o MEU Sum
    {
        public int OnlyEvens(scores){
            public int Above(scores, int threshold)
            {
                return(Evens(Above(scores)).Sum());
            }
            public int Below(scores, int threshold)
            {
                return(Evens(Below(scores)).Sum());
            }
            return(Evens(scores).Sum());
        }
        return(scores.Sum());//este Sum() é proveniente do System.Linq
    }
}
```

Comment: Em qual linguagem? E essa OOP tá meio estranha porque nos exemplos os métodos não são membros de nenhum objeto (`ApplyDamage()` ao invés de `myInstance.ApplyDamage()`). Não consegui entender direito.

Comment: provavelmente era pra ser `chosenTarget.ApplyDamage(.....)`

Comment: Perdão, eu reformulei minha pergunta, e espero que tenha ficado mais claro, obrigado pela ajuda com a definição do problema.

Comment: Qual é o tipo do 1ª parâmetro de Physical()? É uma lista(IEnumerable)?

Comment: Pablo, na verdade "ApplyDamage" é uma função que instancia um "Damage" (não, damage não é uma variável no software que eu estou desenvolvendo) : 
public void ApplyDamage(damage inDamageType, int inAmount, List<GameObject> targets)
{
   Damage tempDamage = new Damage(inDamageType,inAmount);
   foreach(var item in Listeners){
       BroadcastMessage("BeforeApplyDamage",this);
   }
       ChosenTarget.BroadcastMessage("ApplyDamage", this);
   foreach(var item in Listeners){
       BroadcastMessage("AfterApplyDamage", this);
   }       
}

Comment: Ramaral, positivo, "Physical" é um Ienumerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou responder o que dá. A pergunta está confusa e cheio de erros (nem vou comentar o uso do .NET 2.0 que não é suportado mais há um bom tempo). Pode ser que a resposta não seja o que o AP deseja, mas é o que dá para fazer com o que está na pergunta.

Para encadear métodos existe uma técnica chamada [*fluent interface*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101). Quando usada em exagero causa mais mal do que bem.

O segredo para fazer isto é sempre retornar o `this` (o próprio objeto que está sendo manipulado), assim o retorno dele é usado como entrada para o próximo método.

Mas boa parte do código não faz sentido. Como a pergunta não deixa claro o que é preciso fazer, não posso responder mais adequadamente que isto.

O construtor `Roll()` não precisa fazer nada porque ele já retorna o objeto. Na verdade o código na pergunta está errado dizendo que deve retornar `void`, o que me faz pensar que a pergunta é artificial e por isto difícil de responder.

A chamada mostrada de `Sum()` e sua definição não batem. Na verdade a chamada não faz sentido, não tem parenteses, por exemplo, ela deveria ser `.Sum()`.

`OnlyEvens()` e os demais são métodos que devem ser separados. Até a versão 6, o C# não permite métodos dentro de métodos, mesmo na versão 7 o seu uso é para algo completamente diferente. Na verdade isto nem faz sentido aí, colocar um método dentro do outro não atinge o objetivo esperado.

Para fazer isto teria que reformar a classe toda, não sei se compensa. Para que o resultado seja preservado e retorne o `this`, ele deveria ser colocado em algum lugar. Mas aí provavelmente a classe teria um dado espúrio só para atender um requisito falso.

Uma ideia básica:

```
public int Sum() {
    return scores.Sum();
}
public Roll OnlyEvens() {
    return Evens(scores); //imagino que este método existe em algum lugar e faça o esperado
}
public Roll Above(int threshold) {
    return Above(scores, threshold); //se isto não existir, precisa por o algoritmo aqui
}
```

Considerando que `OnlyEvens()` e `Above()` são filtros, eles deveriam ser aplicados antes de fazer a soma:

```
ApplyDamage(Physical(Roll(5, d6).OnlyEvens().Above(2).Sum()), ChosenTarget);
```

Um jeito melhor de fazer o método, se eu entendi o objetivo:

```
public Roll OnlyEvens() {
    scores = scores.Where(x => x % 2);
    return this; //imagino que este método existe em algum lugar e faça o esperado
}
public Roll Above(int threshold) {
    scores = scores.Where(x =>, x > threshold);
    return this;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/InnerMethodDecoupled.cs).

## Conclusão

Acho que tem muita coisa pra ser arrumada antes de obter o resultado esperado. Provavelmente seria melhor fazer funcionar perfeitamente do jeito tradicional e só quando isto ocorrer fazer uma pergunta para mudar para uma interface fluente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou estudar este conceito de fluent interface para analisar uma possibilidade viável dentro da idéia que você propôs...
Atualmente Funciona, mas ... desse jeito :
**Sum(Evens(Above(Roll(5,d6),2)));**


E Roll **"É UMA CLASSE"** (eu preciso que Roll seja uma classe, pois eu estou interceptando o construtor do Roll e fazendo outros métodos interceptadores modificarem o comportamento de Roll(), como modificar os dados rolados, modificar os valores, rerolar valores e etc)

Eu realmente não tinha como escrever algo mais "coeso" porque simplesmente não comecei à reescrever o codigo.