# Tipos de chamadas de Métodos C#

Tags: c#, método

Tenho uma dúvida no seguinte caso, não refente a datas, usei somente como exemplo:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2016 00:00:00").ToShortDateString();
```

Qual a origem deste método `ToShortDateString()` ?

Outro exemplo:

```
var blablabla = string.Copy("asd").Clone().ToString();
```

Como um método pode "chamar" outro método, qual o nome disso?

Comment: `Como um método pode "chamar" outro método, qual o nome disso?` Como dito na resposta do @Juliano é "encadeamento de chamadas". Em casos mais especificos pode ser também chamado de `build pattern` (padrao de construcao)

Comment: Obrigado a todos que responderam, se pudesse marcava as duas respostas. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que é Fluent Interface?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106955/o-que-%c3%a9-fluent-interface)

Comment: @Bacco, esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106955/o-que-%c3%a9-fluent-interface, não responde minha dúvida, a resposta do Juliano é exatamente o que eu gostaria de saber. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @Bacco, para um iniciante como eu, e talvez para outros iniciantes fica mais claro a resposta do Juliano do que a explicação do que é Fluent Interface.

Comment: Concordo o @Robss70, parece mais fácil para min que sou iniciante entender a resposta abaixo do que o design pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagine que temos um método que retorna uma String:

```
public string StringMarota()
```

Eu posso chamar esse método e jogar o resultado numa variável:

```
var marota = StringMarota();
```

Toda string tem o método `ToString`, certo?

```
var manola = marota.ToString();
```

O ponto é que você não está chamando um método no outro, você está chamando um método no retorno do método anterior. Voltando ao nosso exemplo:

```
var marota = StringMarota();
var manola = marota.ToString();
```

Pode ser reduzido para:

```
var manola = StringMarota().ToString();
```

Desde que cada método possua um retorno, você pode ir encadeando as chamadas.

Answer (score 3):

> Como um método pode "chamar" outro método, qual o nome disso?

Você está lendo o código de forma errada. O correto seria afirmar que o **resultado de um método está executando um outro método**.

Este trecho de código

```
Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2016 00:00:00").ToShortDateString();
```

Pode ser convertido da seguinte forma

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2016 00:00:00");
string stringDate = date.ToShortDateString();
```

O que acontece no primeiro exemplo é que você está acessando um método que está disponível no retorno do método executado anteriormente. Como o retorno do metodo `ToDateTime` é um `DateTime`, você tem acesso a todos os métodos disponíveis da instância `DateTime`.

### TLDR;

Apenas para título de informação, algo próximo da citação *"Como um método pode chamar outro método"* pode ser encontrado mais facilmente no javascript, onde é mais comum encontrar uma função que retorna uma outra função. Ainda assim, o código fica um pouco diferente do exemplo citado

```
function soma(arg1){
   return function(arg2){
      return arg1 + arg2;
   }
}

soma(1)(2); //retorna 3
```