# Quando uso objeto.metodo().metodo()?

Tags: java

Boa noite.
Tenho uma dúvida:
quando eu uso uma sintaxe do tipo:
objeto.metodo().metodo()?
Quando e como utilizo esse método?

Comment: Quando precisa fazer isto. Eu posso dizer o que é, quando usa é um pouco mais complicado sem um contexto. Mas poder ser que só queria saber disto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101

Comment: Quando a primeira chamada retorna um objeto não nulo cuja única utilidade que você tem para ele é chamar um método pertencente a esse objeto retornado.

Comment: Meu comentário acima se aplica quando o objeto retornado não é o próprio objeto inicial, quando `objeto.metodo() != objeto`; para casos em que `objeto.metodo() == objeto`, temos uma coisa mais próxima da _fluent API_, conforme mencionado pelo @Maniero

Answer (score 2):

Em poucas palavras sempre quando o método retornar um objeto que vai permitir que possa seja ser acessado através do ponto.

por exemplo:

Eu tenho essa primeira classe aqui, a classe Cachorro, que vai ter como atributos um nome do tipo String, uma idade do tipo int e por ultimo um objeto do tipo Dono. Esse atributo donoDoCachorro vai se comportar igual aos outros atributos, podendo acessar suas propriedades, note também que o nome também é um objecto, já que o String é um object. Após ter compreendido isso, veremos logo depois um construtor que recebe um objecto Dono e um método latir, esse método vai apenas imprimir na tela "Au Au".

```
public class Cachorro{
   String nome;
   int idade;
   Dono donoDoCachorro;

   public Cachorro(Dono dono){
       this.donoDoCachorro = dono;
   }

   public void latir(){
      System.out.println("Au Au");

   }
}
```

Lembrasse que na classe Cachorro tínhamos um atributo do tipo Dono? bom, essa é a classe dele. Ela tem vários atributos, como por exemplo nome, telefone, idade tudo do tipo String, logo abaixo tem um construtor padrão e depois um método apresentar, que vai imprimir na tela o nome e idade do dono.

```
public class Dono{
   String nome;
   String idade;
   String telefone;
   String endereco;

   public Dono(){

   }

   public void apresentar(){
      System.out.println("Olá, meu nome é " + nome + " tenho " + idade " 
                          anos, tudo bem com você?");
   }
}
```

Bom feito e explicado as duas classes, vamos instancia-la (criar as classes). nas primeiras linhas você criou um objeto Dono e instanciou a mesma, e depois criou um objeto cachorro que também instanciou só que desta vez passou como argumento um dono. Espero que tenha compreendido até aqui.

```
public class Teste{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Dono dono = new Dono();
      Cachorro rex = new Cachorro(dono);

      // Agora queremos fazer o cachorro latir, para isso devemos chamar o
      // nome do objeto Cachorro que chamamos de rex, e depois através do 
      // ponto ( . ) acessar os métodos e atributos daquele objeto.

      // veja que acessamos o método latir do cachorro, mas também podemos
      // acessar atributos através do ponto.
      rex.latir();

      // Digamos que queremos sabe a idade do cachorro, basta chama o nome 
      // do objeto, colocar ponto ( . ) e depois colocar o nome do atributo.
      // nesse caso não precisa de parenteses, já que estamos acessando um
      // atributo e não um método.
      rex.idade;

      // Agora queremos acessar o atributo dono do objeto cachorro,
      // lembra-se que esse esse atributo é um objeto? bom prossigamos.
      rex.dono;

      // Bom já acessamos o atributo dono do rex. Mas o atributo dono é 
      // um objeto, isso que dizer que todo vez que estivemos acessando 
      // um atributo que seja um objeto ou um método que retorne um objeto
      // podemos acessar suas propriedades.

      // Por exemplo depois que acessei o atributo dono do rex, quero
      // que o dono se apresente.
      rex.dono.apresentar();

   }
}
```

Podemos fazer isso infinitivamente, e através de métodos e atributos.

Por exemplo assim:

```
objeto.metodo().metodo().metodo();
```

ou assim:

```
objeto.atributo.objeto();
```

ou até mesmo assim:

```
objeto.atributo.objeto().atributo.objeto().atributo;
```

Lembre-se tudo que for objeto ou retornar objeto você pode fazer isso. o cenário é que vai dizer quando e como você deve usar dessa maneira, por exemplo no código que fizemos queriamos acessar o atributo dono do objeto cachorro. e depois acessar o método apresentar do atributo dono. Não existe regra para isso, apenas a prática vai lhe dizer isso.

Answer (score 2):

Isso se chama encadeamento de métodos (method chaining).

Pode ser utilizado para dar mais clareza no código e para usar você precisa que cada método retorne uma instância do objeto que possua, por sua vez, o método a ser chamado na sequência. Por exemplo:

```
class Pessoa {

 private String nome;
 private int idade;
 private String profissao;

 public Pessoa setNome(String nome) {
  this.nome = nome;
  return this;
 }

 public Pessoa setIdade(int idade) {
  this.idade = idade;
  return this;
 }

 public Pessoa setProfissao(String profissao) {
  this.profissao = profissao;
  return this;
 }
}
```

Cada um dos métodos, após ser chamado, retorna uma instância da própria classe, e é isso que nos permite então encadear (ou seja, chamar na sequência) os métodos que queremos.

Em nosso código usaríamos assim:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa().setIdade(30).setNome("Maria").setProfissao("Programadora");
```