# Padrão de projeto builder, por que devo utilizá-lo?

Tags: java, design-pattern

Este exemplo de padrão de projeto pode ser encontrado principalmente no livro "Design Patterns Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software", um livro amplamente conhecido tanto na área acadêmica e também seu conteúdo é amplamente utilizado no mercado de trabalho.

O que eu quero saber é o seguinte:

1. Como seria a melhor maneira de aplicar este padrão?
2. Por que devo usar este padrão? Quando devo utilizá-lo? Por que ele é
   bom?
3. Como seria uma maneira errada de fazer este padrão?
4. Existem falhas neste padrão?
5. Mais alguma coisa a ser acrescentada?

Comment: Poderia adicionar o link da Wikipedia sobre este padrão para fornecer mais contexto?

Comment: O artigo da wikipedia citado na pergunta não é um bom exemplo sobre o padrão Builder.

Comment: Para mim, esse código do `Converter` parece mais com o [padrão Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). A [wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) tem um exemplo melhor de builder

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: @LeonardoLima poderia mostrar o por que não é um bom exemplo e qual seria um bom exemplo para o mesmo?

Isto responderia a questão 1 e 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Como seria a melhor maneira de aplicar este padrão?

Em geral perguntas assim são abertas e muitas vezes dirigidas por opiniões. Mas eu diria que aplica-se melhor seguindo uma fonte confiável (já demonstrado nos comentários que a Wikipedia em português não é).

Quer opinião? Nunca vi necessidade dele, pelo menos nesta forma, mas é só a minha experiência. Mas tem uma [pergunta minha que dá um exemplo onde poderia ser necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/252765/101). Ali tem exemplos mais explicados.

Possíveis fontes confiáveis:

- [oodesign.com](https://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html)
- [Source Making](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)
- [Do Factory](https://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern)

É muito fácil confundi-lo com outros padrões (aliás quase todos os padrões são muito parecidos entre alguns grupos).

> Por que devo usar este padrão? Quando devo utilizá-lo? Por que ele é bom?

Use quando tem objetos muito complexos e que precisam ser construídos de formas diferentes antes de usá-lo, em geral construído em passos. Mas não é só isso, só faz sentido se tiver vários objetos que tenha o mesmo mecanismo básico de construção, mas com detalhes de implementação diferentes. Não o considero bom, na verdade é péssimo, mas se tiver essa necessidade então tem que usar e esta forma foi o que acharam melhor, não sei se realmente é.

Algo parecido com ele pode ser mais útil em algum caso onde você só cria a construção de forma separada de forma simples só para separar a responsabilidade e permitir a construção em passos sem se conformar com um padrão. Mesmo em casos assim só é útil se a construção for muito complexa.

> Como seria uma maneira errada de fazer este padrão?

Difícil responder isso, existem literalmente milhões ou bilhões de formas diferentes de fazer errado. E nem sei se seria errado. Sempre falo que deve fazer o que resolve da melhor forma, mesmo que viole algum padrão.

Não confundir com [Method Chaining](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101) que é um padrão bem diferente mas que é usado para uma construção, e até pode ser usado junto com o Builder. Esse vejo sendo muito mais usado (nem sei se deveria, mas por falhas na linguagem tem sido comum).

> Existem falhas neste padrão?

Certamente, infelizmente não sou especialista nele para dizer, espero que alguém o possa. O que posso dizer é que ele sempre acrescenta muita complexidade, precisa compensar muito para usá-lo, pra mim é a maior falha. E certamente não resolve todas situações.

> Mais alguma coisa a ser acrescentada?

Sempre tem, mas nada que eu ache importante. lembrando que este é o padrão bem pouco usado e por bem poucos dominado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu achei interessante a respota, mas achei que daria para detalhar melhor algumas coisas, por exemplo "Nunca vi necessidade dele, pelo menos nesta forma".

Nesta frase aqui você fala que nunca viu usarem desta forma, então teria uma maneira mais correta de usar e uma menos recomendável, que responderia a questão 1 e 3.

Daria para dar exemplo de por que a forma X não é tão boa quanto a Y, ou por que a forma X seria mais usada e a Y você não vê utilidade.

No caso a maneira que está na Wikipedia não seria um fator determinante, por isto vou remover o link da pergunta.

Comment: Vou ver essas coisas. Embora me parece que a alteração na sua pergunta descaracteriza ela e a minha resposta ficou desatualizada por causa disso, eu terei que apagar partes a resposta porque apagou partes da pergunta, e aí as pessoas não terão essa informação. Ou eu deixarei essas partes e farei referência à versão antiga da pergunta. Quero dizer que não lembro mais o contexto do que eu estava pensando quando eu respondi.

Comment: Bom, só apaguei o link da Wikipedia, na verdade a ideia nunca foi avaliar o que estava lá, mas sim uma visão completa do padrão de projeto builder. Tanto que o conteúdo de lá pode ser atualizado a qualquer momento e pode fazer perder o sentido de qualquer forma.

Então achei melhor retirar o link da Wikipedia.

Comment: Todo o início da minha resposta foi baseada nisso. E aí parte do que pede agora não faz sentido. Inclusive porque o jeito certo de fazer está nos links que eu passei. Eu nem sei que detalhes a mais seria necessário colocar aqui.

Comment: Entendi, bom acho que sem a Wikipedia vai ficar muito melhor. Por que aí daria para falar de uma maneira geral, e não apenas o exemplo de lá. Mas se quiser pode usar o exemplo de lá.

Answer (score -1):

Um complemento a resposta do Maniero, utilizando uma metáfora.

Primeiro a definição, retirada do site [Medium](https://medium.com/@gbbigardi/arquitetura-e-desenvolvimento-de-software-parte-4-builder-848867107f71):

> O padrão Builder faz parte dos padrões criacionais, onde o mesmo tem
> como fundamento a separação da construção de um objeto complexo da sua
> representação, de forma que o mesmo processo de construção possa criar
> diferentes representações, baseado em regras e parâmetros que sejam
> informados ao objeto responsável pela construção.

Imagine que você precisa fazer pães. Para isso vai precisar criar o objeto `Pao`. Para fazer um pão simples vai precisar de farinha, água, fermento e sal, mas se quiser fazer um pão com recheio vai precisar de mais ingredientes.

A solução é estender a classe `Pao` e criar conjuntos de subclasses para representar os parâmetros. Porém, qualquer novo recheio vai precisar de aumentar cada vez mais a quantidade de parâmetros. Para evitar a passagem de vários parâmetros que não serão usados, pois, para fazer uma pão simples você não precisa de colocar recheio, o padrão Builder sugere que você extraia o código de construção do objeto para fora de sua própria classe e mova ele para objetos separados chamados builders.

O padrão organiza a construção de objetos em uma série de etapas, por exemplo, `inserirCamadaPresunto()`, `inserirCamadaMussarela()`..Para criar o objetos você executa essas etapas em um objeto builder. A parte importante é que você não precisa chamar todas as etapas. Chama apenas as que são necessárias para a receita que está fazendo.