# Usar um construtor com vários parâmetros, ou criar vários sets?

Tags: java, desempenho, memória, construtor, getters-setters

Entre **usar um construtor com vários parâmetros** ou **dar um monte de *sets***, qual dessas opções é mais performática para o compilador, custaria menos memória e seria mais rápida?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

As duas perguntas que deve ler antes de mais nada são [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101) e [Métodos Getters e Setters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212300/101) (na verdade aí tem uma lista de perguntas para ler). Sem saber porque usar esses mecanismos não poderá tomar uma decisão adequada.

Ali ficará claro que se vai criar *setters* só para inicializar variáveis está errado.

Até faria sentido se a linguagem permitisse fazer uma inicialização das variáveis e depois não mexer nisso através de *initializers*, aí poderia até ser útil em alguns casos (lendo tudo ali verá que o construtor ainda é necessário em outros, ainda que poderia combinar os dois). Até a data da escrita desta resposta nenhuma linguagem mais conhecida permitia fazer isso. C# permitirá na versão 9 (se tudo correr bem, e não sei se ficará bom, já tenho ressalvas).

Quero reforçar que estritamente falando em orientação a objeto *getters*, e principalmente *setters*, são deturpações. Os proponentes mais fundamentalistas desse paradigma consideram que você só deveria ter métodos mais significativos para operações que por acaso manipula um ou mais campos e provavelmente faz operações que justificam melhor a alteração desses campos, então um *setter* estaria de alguma forma [vazando abstração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354926/101) e expondo o campo indiretamente. Não sou fundamentalista nem grande adepto de OOP, mas procuro pensar sobre isso e adotar o melhor mecanismo. Desenvolver softwares é planejar o que faz, analisando todas as questões possíveis, pelo menos em softwares feitos para durar.

## Alternativas

Em alguns casos pode ser que queira fazer um [padrão *builder*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360658/101) para ajudar, assim pode ir construindo o objeto aos poucos e depois usá-lo como parâmetro do objeto real. É um pouco complexo, consume um pouco mais de recurso pelo menos em determinado momento, mas é mais correto que deixar *setters* expostos só para inicializar os valores.

Em alguns casos é possível agrupar certas partes do seu objeto em objetos menores (`Endereço` ou `AnáliseCrédito` como exemplos) para reduzir bem a quantidade de parâmetros reais a usar. Mas temo que a maioria das pessoas abusará disto e começar modelar errado só para resolver uma questão técnica do código, isso é horrível e muita gente experiente vive fazendo e recomendando, deveria ser a última escolha.

## Muitos parâmetros

Não descarte usar muitos parâmetros no construtor mesmo que pareça errado, não é em muitos casos.

Eu sei que pode ser tornar complicado se tiver muitos dados opcionais (ainda que de alguma forma todos os campos ([não atributos como as pessoas chamam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)) precisam ser inicializados de alguma forma, mesmo que em construtor escrito pelo compilador.

Ás vezes fazer o simples vale mais que fazer o conceitualmente mais certo. Mas eu duvido que criar *setters* só para inicializar o objeto seja melhor em qualquer situação. Se for um método inicializador que você controle que não aceitará mudança depois de um determinado ponto pode ser interessante, mas ele não é um *setter per se*, e será complexo, piorará todo o objeto para evitar o construtor.

## Performance e consumo

A performance não deveria ser uma questão aí, apenas pense nela se for em algo que tenha relevância, normalmente não tem, os cenários que vejo que possa ser acabam não olhando todo o contexto, até porque o grosso do trabalho de construção deve estar em outras questões. Mas o construtor será bem mais rápido na proporção estrita só da chamada desse método ou de outros, no todo a diferença será (bem) pequena.

Chamar vários métodos sempre será mais caro que chamar apenas um, mesmo que tenha muitos parâmetros. [Há um custo intrínseco na chamada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170372/101).

Eu falei da performance de execução, mas a performance para o compilador também será ligeiramente melhor usando o construtor, ainda que dependa um pouco de como fará cada coisa. Isso é menos relevante ainda.

Consumo de memória do objeto em si (no *heap*) será igual, **poderá** haver mais uso da pilha dependendo de como usar o construtor ou os *setters*, mas é menos relevante ainda porque pilha gerencia automaticamente com custo zero então só muda um pouco o custo de processamento, esqueça o seu consumo.

O objeto poderá ser maior usando *setters* se precisar criar um mecanismo para controlar se o objeto está todo construído, o que fará todos os métodos serem menos performáticos ainda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Existe algumas diferenças entre os propósitos do construtor e dos métodos sets:

#### Construtores

A ideia do construtor é **construir o objeto**, ou seja, dar toda a estrutura necessária para que aquele objeto exista.

Por exemplo: em tese, para a receita federal você só existe se tiver um CPF. Logo, faz sentido um objeto do tipo pessoa só existir se ele tiver um CPF. 
Dado esse raciocínio, faz sentido você colocar CPF como um atributo do construtor, já que para que uma pessoa exista, ela precisaria ter CPF.

#### Métodos set

Já os sets são utilizados para **mudar algum atributo** do objeto. Se seu objeto tem campos que podem mudar durante a sua vida, então seu objeto precisa de sets para esses campos.

No exemplo acima, você deve ter o setNome no objeto Pessoa, já que uma pessoa pode mudar o nome durante sua vida. No entanto, se você considerar no seu sistema que uma pessoa nunca deverá mudar de CPF, então você não deve ter um setCPF, já que, nesse caso, o CPF não é um atributo mutável.

### Construtores vs métodos set

Resumindo: **use parâmetros no construtor para os atributos imprescindíveis e métodos sets para os atributos podem ser modificados**.

Quando tiver dúvida, pense se faz sentido aquele objeto existir sem aquele atributo. E lembre-se também que o que for colocado no construtor tem que ser de extrema relevância, pois quanto mais atributos no construtor, maior é a quantidade de valores que deverão, obrigatoriamente, ser passados na hora de instanciar um objeto. Colocar muitos parâmetros no construtor pode gerar um aumento desnecessária de código, o que dificulta a escrita e manutenção do código.

No entanto, muitas vezes todos os atributos de um objeto são muito relevantes. Como, por exemplo, o nome da pessoa no sistema da receita pode ser algo relevante para o objeto Pessoa. Isso vai depender da modelagem do sistema. Na maioria das vezes na programação não existe uma regra definitiva, vai de caso a caso e com a experiência você vai aprendendo como agir em cada caso.

### Performance

Eu não sei qual o mais performático, mas eu chutaria os parâmetros em constutores. Mas garanto-lhe que essa diferença é irrelevante, principalmente quando se trata de uma linguagem de alto nível como Java.
É sempre muito importante se preocupar com performance, principalmente ao fazer loops ou utilizar bibliotecas externas, no entanto, quando se programa em linguagem de alto nível, uma preocupação talvez até mais importante é a de fazer um código legível, organizado e que siga sempre que possível os padrões da Engenharia de Software.

PS: Se realmente tiver a curiosidade, pesquise como fazer testes empíricos na programação e faça seus testes. Testes desse tipo é sempre uma boa forma de aprender mais.

Comment: Sabe que CPF pode ser tanto ou mais mudado que o nome?

Comment: Eu imaginei que provavelmente seria algo mutável também, mas não consegui pensar em algo não mutável no momento. Mas entendo que deveria ter deixado isso mais claro. Vou editar.

Comment: A questão é que se o seu sistema não permitir que a pessoa mude o CPF ele está fundamentalmente errado porque as pessoas mudam independente do seu sistema deixar ou não. Dá para entender o mecanismo, mas ele não é adequado para a realidade do sistemas. E esse é um dos motivos que *getters/setters* serem problemáticos e quase ninguém entende isso. Eles não consideram contexto da mudança. Tudo pode ser mudado por algum motivo, mas não por todos. Para fazer mais ou menos eles nem são necessários (especialmente p *setter*). Mais ou menos organizado é o mesmo que desorganizado.

Comment: Se dentro da lógica do seu sistema, uma pessoa não pode ter mais que um CPF na vida, então você pode optar por não ter set para esse atributo. Caso uma pessoa do mundo real mude o CPF, na visão do sistema ela é outra pessoa e é papel do desenvolvedor saber lidar com isso. Não creio que seja algo "fundamentalmente errado". Toda modelagem vai ter prós e contras.

Comment: Eu entendo o seu comentário, mas eu sempre enxerguei isso como uma limitação da OO (e também de toda a computação). Infelizmente não dá para modelar tudo exatamente como é no mundo real. Em muitos casos é muito útil o uso de sets, mas sim, concordo que em muitos outros casos, chega a ser meio idiota o uso.

Comment: Esse seria um sistema fantasioso por isso ele é fundamentalmente errado. E tem sistemas assim, eu sei porque sou vítima deles. Não pode fazer o correto porque o sistema não permite, aí faz o erro e ferra tudo. Eu gostaria que as pessoas parassem de fazer sistemas fundamentalmente errados porque ela pensa no sistema dela e não na necessidade de quem usa que sempre é real.

Comment: Não vi que tinha adicionado uma resposta. Entendi seu ponto.
Só acho a resposta meio pesada para um iniciante (ashuashaus), mas é importante saber disso.

Comment: Blz,Obrigado pessoal!!