# Sobrecarga de métodos não está chamando o método

Tags: java, tipagem, método

Meu código está apresentando erro, não consegui identificá-lo.

```
 public class Inicial {
     public static void main (String args []) {
         Texto t = new Texto("a b c d e");
         t.adiciona(new Frase("x y")).adiciona(" f g h i");
         System.out.println(t);
     }
 } 

 class Frase {
     String frase;
     Texto tx;

     Frase(String frase) {
         this.frase = frase;
     }
 }

 class Texto {
     String t;
     String ns;
     Frase f[];
     int qtd;

     Texto(String t) {
         this.t = t;
         f = new Frase[10];
         qtd= 0;
     }

     void adiciona(Frase fra) {
        ns.concat(fra.frase);
     }

     void adiciona(String s) {
         ns = t.concat(s);
     }

     public String toString() {
        return ns;
     }
 }
```

Erro:

> ```
> Cannot invoke adiciona(String) no the primitive type void
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos destrinchar esta linha:

```
t.adiciona(new Frase("x y")).adiciona(" f g h i");
```

Aqui o `t` representa o objeto criando anteriormente. Com ele podemos invocar todos os métodos de instâncias (não estáticos) disponíveis na classe desse objeto, no caso `Texto`. Por isso podemos chamar qualquer um dos dois métodos `adiciona()` sem problemas. E é o que é feito a seguir quando chama `adiciona(new Frase("x y"))`, passando uma `Frase` para ele.

O que este método retorna? Nada. Nenhum problema até agora.

Qual é o objeto que temos agora como resultado da chamada deste método? Nenhum. Já sabemos que pode chamar um método que esteja disponível no objeto que estamos manipulando, que agora é nada. Então não podemos chamar método algum. Mas é o que foi feito, e aí deu o erro.

Como solucionar isto?

Uma forma é adotar a chama da [Fluent Interface](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101), onde um método retorno o próprio objeto que está manipulando:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        Texto t = new Texto("a b c d e");
        t = t.adiciona(new Frase("x y")).adiciona(" f g h i");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
} 

class Frase {
    String frase;

    Frase(String frase) {
        this.frase = frase;
    }
}

class Texto {
    String t;

    Texto(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    Texto adiciona(Frase fra) {
       t = t.concat(fra.frase);
       return this;
    }

    Texto adiciona(String s) {
        t = t.concat(s);
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
       return t;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SZ1Oyy). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/kembovxesp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/Fluent.java).

Fiz modificações porque o código como um todo tinha outros erros e tirei o que nem sabemos porque está aí.

Ou podemos evitar de fazer o encadeamento, assim operando sempre no objeto que deseja:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        Texto t = new Texto("a b c d e");
        t.adiciona(new Frase("x y"));
        t.adiciona(" f g h i");
        System.out.println(t);
    }
} 

class Frase {
    String frase;

    Frase(String frase) {
        this.frase = frase;
    }
}

class Texto {
    String t;

    Texto(String t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    void adiciona(Frase fra) {
       t = t.concat(fra.frase);
    }

    void adiciona(String s) {
        t = t.concat(s);
    }

    public String toString() {
       return t;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/iH0Ujf). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/lvdzkowksb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/JustVoid.java).

Não entrei nas questões de (in)eficiência do código, até por naõ ter detalhes sobre o objetivo.