# Qual seria o equivalente ao "with" do Javascript em Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Olá,
Eu estava estudando essa nova "linguagem" que parece prometedora, quando me deparei com isso. Não existe essa expressão em Coffeescript ou algo similar?

Comment: Essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52604/para-que-serve-o-with-no-javascript/161214#161214) do @bigown diz que o with não é recomendado pelo fato de trazer ambiguidade. Porque gostaria de usar uma função em que o uso não é recomendado?

Comment: @Marconi, por mais uma questão de capricho, eu acho que fica elegante visualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O CoffeeScript eliminou o uso do `with`, caso você tente usar você recebera uma mensagem de `syntax error`.

O proprio uso de `with` no javascript não é recomendado, ele é considerado `deprecated` e deve ser removido num futuro próximo.

Nesse [livro da O'Reilly de referência de CoffeeScript](https://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/07_the_bad_parts.html) o Autor usa o `with` como exemplo de partes do javascript que o CoffeeScript se antecipou e retirou.

Comment: Obrigado, isso foi de grande ajuda :)