# Por que não é uma boa ideia usar "with" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estava lendo sobre a documentação de [JavaScript na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), onde é mencionado que:

> **Aviso:** O uso da declaração with não é recomendado, isso porque ele pode ser a fonte de bugs confusos e problemas de compatibilidade. Veja o parágrafo "Contra de ambiguidade" na seção "Descrição" para mais detalhes.

Ele deixa claro que não é uma boa ideia usar o `with` com JavaScript. Atualmente, eu tive a ideia de usar ele porque eu tenho um objeto com um caminho muito grande para chegar até ele, então encurtei com:

```
with (user = res.response.users[0].creating_user) {
   ...
}
```

Assim não preciso ficar chamando em todos os lugares `res.response.users[0].creating_user` e descarto o ponteiro para ele assim que terminar o bloco.

Achei bem útil fazer isso, mas a documentação diz que essa expressão confunde alguns compiladores.

Devo realmente evitar usar o `with`?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52604/101 dup?

Comment: @Maniero sim, essa fecha a pergunta. Juro q procurei mas não achei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente o `with()` não funciona no *strict mode*, então o ideal é usar algo que funcione tanto em modo estrito quanto em não estrito

```js
// Irá executar normalmente

with (['foo', 'bar']) {
  console.log(toString());
}
```

```js
// Irá emitir: SyntaxError: 'with' statements are not valid in strict mode.

'use strict';
 
with (['foo', 'bar']) {
  console.log(toString());
}
```

O `with` tem alguns problemas com:

- Possíveis problemas de desempenho
- A leitura/identificação pode tornar o código confuso
- É um pouco mais complicado de depurar
- [**ECMAScript Modules** são sempre strict mode](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), então não poderá usar `with()` nesse caso especifico
- Alguns runtimes podem usar por padrão *strict mode*

Note que no ECMA 2015 foi introduzido o [`Array.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values), então um exemplo como esse (obtido no MDN):

```js
function foobar(foo, values) {
  with (foo) {
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

Então se chamar `foobar([1, 2, 3], obj)` em **ECMAScript 5**, a referência de valores dentro da instrução `with()` será o `obj`, mas em **ECMAScript 2015** irá retornar [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values) do array `foo`.

Claro que sabendo o que está fazendo e exatamente como funciona, não irá ter tal problema, mas é o tipo de situação que causa confusão.

### Por que ainda não foi removido?

Apesar disso tudo é improvável que será removido pelos motivos citados em [tc39wiki](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/about/faq/#breaking)

> Se o fizéssemos, o conteúdo da web existente seria interrompido. Nenhum fornecedor de navegador está disposto a ser o primeiro a fazer essas alterações, porque um usuário final racional as percebe como bugs do navegador e muda para um navegador diferente.
>
> A única vez que podemos fazer uma alteração incompatível é se a web não depender dela. Não há como saber com certeza se esse é o caso, exceto experimentando. Os fornecedores de navegadores podem arriscar fazendo uma alteração incompatível nas versões alfa ou beta de seus navegadores e ver se eles recebem algum relatório de bug sobre quebra de conteúdo.

Então não quer dizer de fato que será removido.

### Alternativa ao `with()`, que funciona com ou sem strict mode

Existem muitos meios de atingir algo aproximado (não exatamente iguais), no geral é atribuindo a uma nova variável, mas se o objetivo é também isolar o escopo você pode usar **IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)** ou até mais simples, usar o [**`block` (`{...}`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block#Block_scoping_rules_with_var_or_function_declaration_in_non-strict_mode) (não use com `var`, apenas com `const` ou `let`):

```js
{
   const user = res.response.users[0].creating_user;
   ...
}
```

Dessa forma a constante `user` fica acessível só dentro do escopo, se fizer tentar acessar fora do escopo irá falhar:

```js
const res = { response: { user: 'cypher' } };

{
   const user = res.response.user;

   console.log({ user });
}

console.log({ user });
```

Comment: Supri a necessidade criando um método super simples que "faz o que o with faz": https://jsfiddle.net/djzwpL1s/

Comment: @CypherPotato simplificando mais ainda: `const m = minha_variavel_com_nome_gigante;`